# Reusing simple BDD testing for more complex test scenarios

Tags: bdd, cucumber, reusability

I am currently learning about BDD (Cucumber/Gherkin) in test automation. I am wondering about reusing simpler test scenarios or step definitions for more complex scenarios. Specifically, I am working on network testing. For example, say I have the following (generic) test scenario:

```
Given a switch with ports {port1}, {port2} with access on VLAN {vlan}
And traffic generator connected to ports {port1}, {port2}
And bi-directional traffic on VLAN {vlan}
When port {port1} is down
Then traffic is {lost|recovered|whatever is expected}
```

Now, say I have a more complex environment. I still want to run this same test to ensure traffic responds accordingly. Can I reuse the BDD step definitions for this more complex environment, or is this not an appropriate use-case for BDD? Or, is this really just about how I organize my test scenarios and step definitions?

Comment: the gherkin is just a long winded way of writing a function name and parameters. how reusable that function is depends on the code, which you have not shown.

Comment: I think your question is unclear. When this test scenario *definition* describes a requirement which exists in different environments, you can use the definition for each of the environments, that is trivial, so that is not your question, I guess? . Or is your questher if an *implemention* of this scenario can be reused for different environments? That depends on the API compatibility of the software under test within the different environments.

Answer (score 0):

What’s complicating your “more complex environment”?

BDD tests require two things. The behavior they are testing and an API through which they are testing that behavior. Change either and you break the test.

But change implementation choices that leave those two intact and the test still passes. That’s fine. We call that refactoring.

If your situation has changed enough that the test no longer applies that’s a full blown requirements change. You’ll need to rewrite the test so that it applies to your new needs.

Comment: Thanks! In this case, it would be the test environment that would change. For example, I want to make sure traffic passes appropriately with a single switch as well as with a larger network that includes multiple devices, routing protocols, etc. So it may be a different "feature" (i.e. routing protocol) I'm testing, but I would still want to run the same test. Does that make sense? Is that a case of refactoring? Most examples I see with BDD are very simple straightforward tests. It makes sense it would be reusable in the way I am describing, but I can't find examples, which is throwing me off.

Comment: It’s a refactoring if the behavior being tested and the API it’s tested through is the same. How it works inside doesn’t matter to the test. Only that it works.